# Creating a class whose methods can be called without an instance of an object (static class)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm new to objective c and i want to create a class containing certain methods that can be called in any of my other classes, mostly helper methods. im still learning the syntax and i dont know how to declare it properly

kind of like in java `Integer.parseInt(    );`

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Static methods in objective-c are called 'class methods' and can be declared with '+' symbol (while instance methods with '-'), e.g.:

```
- (void) instanceMethod;
+ (void) classMethod;
```

To call class method use class name:

```
[MyClass classMethod];
```

Comment: In Obj-C they're called class methods, not static methods.

Answer (score 4):

Those are called (unsurprisingly) class methods. You can declare one by using `+` instead of `-` in the method signature, e.g.

```
@interface MyInteger : NSObject
+ (MyInteger *)parseInt:(NSString *)str;
@end
```

This method is then called on the class itself, e.g. `[MyInteger parseInt:@"12"]`.

Of course, since this is C, if your class method doesn't actually have much relation to any particular class, you could just define it as a C function instead.

```
NSInteger myParseInt(NSString *str);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you see a `-` sign in front of a method, it's an instance method. That means you can only call that method on an instance of a class.

If you want to create a class method, all you need to do is change that `-` to a `+`.

Answer (score 1):

they are called class methods. they are declared and used like this:

```
@interface MONClass : NSObject

+ (NSString *)convertString:(NSString *)string;

@end
```

in use:

```
NSString * converted = [MONClass convertString:string];
```